# how to increment a date and time on a hyperlink automatically

Tags: c#, datetime

For Example.

https://*****************/?post=5777&sort=&page=1&start=**2021-06-27%2000:00**&end=**2021-06-28%2023:59**

I am trying to change the the date by incrementing it and automatically download it. can anyone help me change the text on the hyperlink to increase the date? I can't change it.

Comment: Please explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: sorry, I've changed it thank you.

Comment: You can use [`Uri`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Uri__ctor_System_String_) to parse the URL, and then take the `Query` property of that and feed it into [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Web_HttpUtility_ParseQueryString_System_String_) to get a [`NameValueCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=net-5.0), which will let you access the query parameters